# importing high resolution photos android app not working

Tags: android, photo

im using a basic programm to import images from my phone to an app i wrote and it works fine.
The only problem is when I want to import high resolution photos (+9 Mpx) the photo wont show up

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_new_user);

contactImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ChosenPhoto); 

public void onActivityResult(int reqCode,int resCode, Intent data) {
      contactImgView.setImageURI(data.getData());
}



public void AddPicture(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select contact image"),1);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because it's too high resolution.

You will have to decode that bitmap using [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) methods with [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) first detecting resolution of image using [inJustDecodeBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds) and then after counting if outWidth*outHeight > moreThenAppCanHandle you can decode it using [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) with appropriate factor, which will decrease output image resolution appropriately which means less memory consumed.

Hopefuly this will work and will help you.